# Getting a TIMESTAMP from postgre as a LocalDatetime with HibernateORM

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this Hibernate model

```java
package net.nebulacraft.nebulous.Data.Models;

import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "warning")
public class Warning {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "warningid")
    int WarningId;
    @Column(name = "userid")
    UUID Player;
    @Column(name = "rulenumber")
    int RuleNumber;
    @Column(name = "expiration")
    LocalDateTime Expiration;
    @Column(name = "datecreated")
    LocalDateTime DateCreated;
    @Column(name = "warnedby")
    UUID WarnedBy;
    @Column(name = "message")
    String Message;
    public UUID getPlayer() {
        return Player;
    }
    public void setPlayer(UUID player) {
        Player = player;
    }
    public int getRuleNumber() {
        return RuleNumber;
    }
    public void setRuleNumber(int ruleNumber) {
        RuleNumber = ruleNumber;
    }
    public LocalDateTime getExpiration() {
        return Expiration;
    }
    public void setExpiration(LocalDateTime expiration) {
        Expiration = expiration;
    }
    public LocalDateTime getDateCreated() {
        return DateCreated;
    }
    public void setDateCreated(LocalDateTime dateCreated) {
        DateCreated = dateCreated;
    }
    public UUID getWarnedBy() {
        return WarnedBy;
    }
    public void setWarnedBy(UUID warnedBy) {
        WarnedBy = warnedBy;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return Message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        Message = message;
    }
    public int getWarningId() {
        return WarningId;
    }
    public void setWarningId(int warningId) {
        WarningId = warningId;
    }
}
```

I can insert a new Warning into the database with `session.save(warning); session.getTransaction().commit();`, warning being an instance of Warning and session being a hibernate session. However, trying to get an instance of Warning from the database like this

```java
    public static List<Warning> GetWarnings(UUID player) {
        var session = DbFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        var builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        var query = builder.createQuery(Warning.class);
        var root = query.from(Warning.class);

        query.select(root);
        query.where(
                builder.and(
                        builder.equal(root.get("Player"), player),
                        builder.greaterThan(root.get("Expiration"), new Date())
                )
        );
        query.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("DateCreated")));
        return session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
```

results in the following error:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to class java.time.LocalDateTime (java.util.Date and java.time.LocalDateTime are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Hibernate seems to have no problem inserting a LocalDatetime into the database, why can't I get one back from the database?

Both the Expiration and DateCreated columns have data type "timestamp without time zone" in postgre

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said:

> Both the Expiration and DateCreated columns have data type "timestamp without time zone" in postgre

## Wrong type in database

You are using the wrong data type for your database columns.

The `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` Postgres type purposely lacks any concept of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this type cannot be used to represent a moment, cannot be a specific point on the timeline.

When tracking a moment, a specific point on the timeline, always use a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

## Wrong type in Java

Likewise, you are using the wrong Java class.

The `LocalDateTime` class, purposely lacks any concept of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this type cannot be used to represent a moment, cannot be a specific point on the timeline.

Instead use `OffsetDateTime` class to retrieve values from a column of [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Both `Date` classes are now legacy, years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

There is no need to use the legacy classes. Their functionality is entirely replaced by the *java.time* classes.

- `java.util.Date` is replaced by `java.time.Instant`.
- `java.sql.Date` is replaced by `java.time.LocalDate`.

For database work, use:

- `java.time.OffsetDateTime` for database columns of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.
- `java.time.LocalDateTime` for database columns of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

[JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2+, [Jakarta Persistence (JPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence), and [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_(framework)) have all been updated to support *java.time*.

Comment: This results in the same error but OffsetDateTime instead of LocalDateTime `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to class java.time.OffsetDateTime (java.util.Date and java.time.OffsetDateTime are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Comment: Actually, it seems like I had 2 problems one of which was this and the other was because I was later comparing it to a java Date. I will therfore mark this answer as correct

Comment: @GradynWursten I added the last section address the `Date` issue.